# Combining unique elements of a DataFrame in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'll try to ask my question as clearly as possible.

I have the following DataFrame which looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'player' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       'game' : ['Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Ping pong', 'Soccer', 'Tennis', 'Tennis', 'Baseball', 'Volleyball', 'Dodgeball']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['player','game'])

  player        game
0      A      Soccer
1      A  Basketball
2      A   Ping pong
3      B      Soccer
4      B      Tennis
5      B      Tennis
6      C    Baseball
7      C  Volleyball
8      C   Dodgeball
```

Now I want to keep values unique to each player only once. Ideally in a list, but that's not a big deal.

For example, player `A` and `B` play `soccer` so I don't want soccer in the output.
`tennis` appears twice, but both for player `B` so it would be in the output.

I'd want to output to be :

```
player        game
0      A  Basketball
1      A   Ping pong
2      B      Soccer
3      B      Tennis
4      C    Baseball
5      C  Volleyball
6      C   Dodgeball
```

Or like this:

```
player        game
0      A  [Basketball, Ping Pong]
1      B  [Soccer, Tennis]
2      C  [Baseball, Volleyball, Dodgeball]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Answer was reopened, because wrongly closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems need remove duplicates with keep last per column 'game' by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then if need lists aggregate them by `list`:

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates('game', keep='last')
        .groupby('player')['game']
        .agg(list)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  player                               game
0      A            [Basketball, Ping pong]
1      B                   [Soccer, Tennis]
2      C  [Baseball, Volleyball, Dodgeball]
```